# How to prove that $A_4 = \langle(1, 2)(3, 4),(1, 2, 3)\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

As per [this Wiki](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_group:A5), the subgroup (of $A_5$) $A_4 = \langle(1, 2)(3, 4),(1, 2, 3)\rangle$. How to show that $(1, 2)(3, 4),(1, 2, 3)$ generates the whole alternating group $A_4$?

I know for a fact that the alternating groups (for $n \geq 3$) can be generated by 3-cycles. So I guess I need to show that *any* 3-cycle can be generated by $(1, 2)(3, 4)$ and $(1, 2, 3)$. Any idea about how to proceed?

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the two elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this is clearly a subgroup of $A_4$, because the generators are there. $(123)$ being in the subgroup implies that its square $(132)$ is there as well. Next, $(12)(34)(123)=(243)$ is in the subgroup, hence its square $(234)$ as well. We can multiply again and get that $(123)(243)=(124)$ is in the subgroup. Together with the identity and $(12)(34)$ we already found $7$ elements of this subgroup of $A_4$. Since $|A_4|=12$ Lagrange's theorem tells us it must be the whole group $A_4$.

Answer (score 1):

How many $3-$ cycles are there? $(123), (132), (124), (142), (134), (143), (234), (243)$.
So you have to prove all eight elements can be generated from the given elements. Hint: Square $(123)$. Can you generate the remaining cycles?